# adding font awesom 4.5 to bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

If my site is running bootstrap 3, and i want to add font awesome 4.5, what should i do with the font awesome files that are packaged with bootstrap 3

will this "overlap" of fonts hit performance in any way ?

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't come packaged with FontAwesome. Bootstrap uses Glyphicons. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: Thanks Chris. 
the similarity between FontAwesome and Glyphicons threw me off

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install FA following the instructions, there's no problem, works just fine :-)